# Having the 'Tuple' has no attribute k

Tags: python, tuples, attributeerror

So I created a set of libraries that makes it easier for me to track my LoL Stats over the course of the season, for that I have a class game:

```
class game:

    def __init__(self,kills,deaths,assists,pos,champ,cs,tk,wl,length = time(0,20,0)):
        self.k = kills
        self.a = assists
        self.d = deaths
        self.l = length
        self.p = pos
        self.c = champ
        self.cs = cs
        self.tk = tk
        self.wl = wl
```

and a class gl (GameList)

```
class gl:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ki = []
        self.ass = []
        self.de = []
        self.ch = []
        self.po = []
        self.le = []
        self.csc = []
        self.tki = []
        self.wil =[]
```

Now when I use the method self.add() in the gl class where g is an object of the class game:

```
def add(self,g):
    self.ki.append(g.k)
    self.ass.append(g.a)
    self.de.append(g.d)
    self.ch.append(g.c)
    self.po.append(g.p)
    l = g.l.traM()
    self.le.append(l)
    self.csc.append(g.cs)
    self.tki.append(g.tk)
    if game.wl == True:
        self.wil.append("Win") 
    else:
        self.wil.append("Loss")
```

I get the Error: *AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'k'*

Now when I tried this earlier it worked fine and I have no Idea why it stopped working the only thing that change was that I installed matplotlib and used that to create a few methods involving piecharts.

I would be happy if someone could help me out and maybe provide a solution, since I am fairly new to python but programmed in Pascal before.

Comment: Well, what are you passing as `g`? If it is a `tuple`, then thats your answer, since a tuple does not have those attributes. Maybe you used a `namedtuple` before?

Comment: Are you sure? Because that error message is saying otherwise. Maybe you overwrote the variable by accident. You can alway do a `print(type(g), g)` before the call to check.

Comment: Look for an involuntary tuple creation (for example, an extra comma in the end of a grouping parenthesis)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: No it was a stupid mistake, I forgot to define one of the games as an object of that class by writing the name of the class before the parenthesis and I didn't notice due to the sheer bulk of past data I wrote today so it was not the coding of the class, but the writing of the main program mb

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to Python, if you haven't already met **type()** let me introduce you :-)  The **type()** function will show you what something is.  To troubleshoot your code try adding some **print** statements like this:

```
def add(self,g):
    print('add() type(g)={}'.format(type(g)))
    print('add() g={}'.format(g))
    self.ki.append(g.k)
    self.ass.append(g.a)
    self.de.append(g.d)
```

Once you find out what kind of thing **g** is go ahead and edit your question and let us know.  Like @Graipher says it is probably something different than you expect.

Once you get that working, from a design point of view it seems easier to keep a list of **Game** instances instead of a list of all the individual attributes.

```
class gl2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.games = [ ] # list to hold games

    def __str__(self):
        return 'gl2(#games={})'.format(len(self.games)))

    def add(self, g):
        self.games.add(g)
```

Adding **__str__()** methods can make it much easier to see what your classes are doing.  You might want to add one to your **game** class, if nothing else just to make debugging easier:

```
class game:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'game(#kills={})'.format(len(self.k)))
```